# How to run a Vue JS build in development mode (Using Vue UI)

Tags: vue.js, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my Vue app in development mode. When I click on the Vue Chrome extension indicator it says:

> Vue.js is detected on this page. Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author

When I run the build task in Vue UI it defaults to production. How do I switch this to development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

In Vue UI in the build section click the "Parameters" button next to the green build button.

This opens up the Parameters dialog, were one of the options is **Specifiy env mode** Switch this to "development" and then run build